# convert opacity to solid color in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Creating a document in publisher I want to get all my pictures in vector format.

I've created one using inkscape and the only common format for publisher & inkscape is ehanced metafile (*.emf).
The problem is metafile does not support opacity

I found this solution but it uses illustrator
[Illustrator: Getting solid color values from transparency?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28962/illustrator-getting-solid-color-values-from-transparency)

so I looked for flattening transparency for inkscape but this is the only clue I got:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/951816 and no update since...

any idea how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Good find on the big report.  I recommend you comment on the bug report with an update, so it comes to the attention of the developers again.

Comment: Bugs are currently being migrated to gitlab: http://alpha.inkscape.org/bug-migration/ - it would make sense to move it instead of bumping it.

Aside from that, as all the objects are overlapping, the quickest solution would be to export the drawing as a PNG file, and trace that with Inkscape. Choosing the correct number of colors will make it easier to reassign them with the dropper tool after the scan, if they don't match.
Or you could: 1. redraw, using the snapping function and the Bézier tool, or 2. do lots of Boolean operations to split the overlapping areas into separate objects.

Comment: I don't use Publisher, but if it can import a PDF, that might be a solution. Have you tried that?

Comment: I got the same result importing it into a pdf

Comment: using open office drawing  instead of MS publisher is the best solution I found so far since it can support svg pictures